# Accessing the ordinal column index of a collection via AJAX

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, linq

I have a control on my website which is rendered from a JSON string which has the basic form:

```
<div class="drugCard">
    <span>DrugId: 1</span>
    <span>DrugClass: HHH </span>
    <span>DrugDosage: 100 </span>
    <span>DrugName: Drug1</span>
</div>
```

The `Drugs` object is the containing div and the text inside the span tags represents the property name.  I'm trying to use jQuery to find the index of the span tag and send that index to a `ScriptMethod` so I can use LINQ to query the database without having to write a bunch of stored procedures.  The following little bit of AJAX code sends the correct data to the server:

```
 $('.drugCard span').click(function () {
                console.log($(this).index());
                var index = JSON.stringify({ 'index': $(this).index() });
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "../Service.asmx/LinqTest",
                    data: index,
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data.d);
                        console.log('the ajax call was successful');
                    },
                    error: function (xhr) {
                        console.log('the ajax call failed');
                        console.log(xhr.status);
                    }
                });
            });
```

The following server-side method isn't reading from a database for simplicity's sake:

```
   [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod]
    public string LinqTest(int index)
    {
        List<Drugs> drugList = new List<Drugs>()
        {
            new Drugs() { DrugId=1, DrugClass="HHH", DrugDosage=120, DrugName="Drug1"},
            new Drugs() { DrugId=2, DrugClass="H2H", DrugDosage=100, DrugName="Drug2"},
            new Drugs() { DrugId=3, DrugClass="HHH", DrugDosage=100, DrugName="Drug3"},
            new Drugs() { DrugId=4, DrugClass="WA2", DrugDosage=200, DrugName="Drug4"}
        };
            var query = (from d in drugList
                         select d[index]).Max().ToString();

            return query;
        }
```

This gives me the error: `cannot apply indexing [] to an expression....`.  My web page won't always have the property name prefaced like it is here.  Is there a way I can use an indexer with LINQ to accomplish what I want (the LINQ query here is just a trivial placeholder for more intensive stuff).

Comment: What is the intent of `d[index]`? That won't work in or out of `Linq`.

Comment: It's meant to get the ordinal index of a property of an object.  So there are four properties of the Drugs object, each one corresponds to a span tag inside of the div.  The first span in the div contains information about DrugId.  Instead of writing a stored procedure to get a max or min of each property, I want to send the column on which to search as a variable.

Comment: The .NET side of things has no idea what property the index maps to. You can use something like dynamic linq if you can pass the property name, but as far as .NET is concerned there is no "order" of the properties to go off of (and that shouldn't be tied to the order on the front-end). Can you pass a property name instead?

Comment: @Ocelot20 Sure, I could pass a property name as well.